# JavaScript Merge issue in Magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, javascript, onepage-checkout

I have one issue, I enabled JavaScript merge option in magento backed but iam getting many issues in checkout page. Please see the image. anyone please help.
I need javascript merge because i saw javascript merge issue in page speed.
[image: Checkout Page Error]

Comment: Did you find a fix for this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand the core principle here what conflicts between javascript libraries and what not.

In case of jQuery and Prototype conflict and in Magento:

1) Always include jQuery before any other script on your page , before Prototype is a must

2) Add jQuery.noConflict(); call directly to the end of your jQuery library file

3) Make sure that none of your jQuery based scripts are not using $ as method name (essence of the conflict here)

4) Try to replace minimized Javascript files with non-minimized versions of those files. And it always solved the problems.

Try this,it will solve your problem

Comment: I have the same issue, It's something to do with the JS files for onepage not merging correctly and will not work when merge JavaScript is enabled on Magento 1.9.3 . It was reported on the github page for some time and still is an issue.